# Warning: Text content did not match... but it does

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm experimenting with SSR since I've never touched the subject before and want to learn more about it. I've built a simple SSR and it works fine, except when I add some variables in the mix.

This works fine:

```
<span>msg: hello</span>
```

This cast an error:

```
const txt = 'hello';
...
<span>msg: {txt}</span>
```

`Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "msg: hello" Client: "msg: "`

If I check the doc request this is what I get from localhost:

```
<span>msg: hello</span>
```

and when I inspect element:

```
<span>
"msg: "
"hello"
</span>
```

My initial thinking is that the hydration does not read the next line, and just see "msg: ", even tho, it looks fine in the dom and all the data is correct.

I can, however make it work with a templatestring `` <span>{`msg: $txt}`}</span> ``
but I have several cases where I check what to print with a function.

Anyone got more information on this one, how can I make React hydration to be more open minded and check for the next line?

Answer (score 1):

check if you use `renderToString`, and not `renderToStaticMarkup`.

Similar problem: https://lihautan.com/hydrating-text-content/